# Make just one slide different size in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

Making a powerpoint that's supposed to show a before and after of a website.  Since it's currently a long website I'd rather make a single long slide to put it on (20" instead of 7.5").  But all the other slides in the presentation should be normal-sized.

I found Slide Size (Design ribbon, Customize section) but that resizes ALL slides.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  You can only have one slide size and one orientation per presentation.

Are you projecting the presentation or delivering it on a laptop?
If so, the size is sort of irrelevant.
Regardless of the slide size, the projected/displayed image will never be longer or wider than the projector/display accepts.

Answer (score 7):

Although you cannot use different sized slides in one PowerPoint file, for the actual presentation you can link several different files together to create a presentation that has different slide sizes.

The process to do so is as follows:

1. Create the two Powerpoints (with your desired slide dimensions)

   - They need to be properly filled in to have linkable objects and selectable slides
2. Select an object in the main PowerPoint to act as the hyperlink
3. Go to "Insert -> Links -> Action"
4. Select either the "Mouse Click" or the "Mouse Over" tab
5. Select "Hyperlink to:" and in the drop down menu choose "other PowerPoint Presentation"
6. Select the slide that you want to link to.

   - Any slide that isn't empty should appear in the "Hyperlink to Slide" dialog box
7. Repeat the Process in the second Presentation to link back to your main presentation

Reference to Office Support Page where this solution was first posted.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/can-i-use-portrait-and-landscape-slide-orientation-in-the-same-presentation-d8c21781-1fb6-4406-bcd6-25cfac37b5d6?ocmsassetID=HA010099556&CorrelationId=1ac4e97f-bfe6-47b1-bab6-5783e78d126d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1):

True you can't have different sized slides.  NOT true the size of you slide doesn't matter.  It will size it to your resolution, but you can click on the magnifying icon(at least on PP 2013) and you can then scroll in all directions of your slide in original resolution.

Comment: I wonder if 2016 behaves differently; I set up two slides, one the standard 16:9 (13.333 x 7.5) the other double that size.  Zoom during slide show gives me the same results in each.

Comment: I can't see that 2016 does anything differently; in the resize dialog box I saw a "Number slides from" option and I hoped that was a poorly implemented and named option to begin slide resizing from a particular slide number... that's not the case - resizing then occurred to all slides in the Presentation.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to shrink one slide for instance, add shapes to hide the unwanted background margins. you can set the shape color filling as the background (gray or black).
It's "ugly" but it works

Answer (score 0):

true, this option is not available in any version of MS ppt.Now the solution is that You put your different sized slide in other file and put a hyperlink in first file.